# How to group result of a group by in the same column (Oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a query that results in "RESULT 1"

This is a GROUP BY in X, Y, Z and W and a SUM in VALUE. but I want the W / VALUE pair  grouped in the same column like the result "RESULT 2".

Is there an efficient way to do that in Oracle?

RESULT 1:

```
X                  Y                          Z                   W   VALUE
-- ----------------- -------------------------- -------------------- ---------- 
45                 18                          1                  101  1,12 
45                 18                          1                  104  1,12 
45                 18                          1                  137  2,58 
45                 18                          1                  216  6,06 
45                 18                          1                  218  5,9 
45                 18                          1                  223  7,08 
45                 18                          1                  302  4,86 
45                 18                          1                  303  4,68 
45                 18                         11                  101  9,38 
45                 18                         11                  104  9,38 
45                 18                         11                  201  9,38 
45                 18                         13                  118  9,21 
45                 18                         13                  137  2,69 
45                 18                         13                  201  9,38
```

RESULT 2:

```
X                  Y                          Z                   W   VALOR    W   VALOR W    VALOR W    VALOR W    VALOR W  VALOR W    VALOR W    VALOR
-- ----------------- -------------------------- -------------------- ---------- 
45                 18                          1                  101  1,12   104  1,12  137  2,58  216  6,06  218  5,9 223  7,08  302  4,86  303  4,68 
45                 18                         11                  101  9,38   104  9,38  201  9,38 
45                 18                         13                  118  9,21   137  2,69  201  9,38
```

Comment: i think you're looking for [PIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

Comment: A SQL query returns a fixed number of columns.  The only way to do what you want in SQL is by using dynamic SQL, unless you know the maximum number of `W` values.